# How to migrate Zend Framework plugins to Zend Framework 2 application skeleton

Tags: php, zend-framework, plugins, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I got Akrabat's tutorial working with doctrine 2 modules.

I'm trying to figure out how to migrate plugins, action helpers, view helpers etc to Zend Framework 2. There seems to be no tutorials or blog articles regarding this...

Comment: ZF2 is completely new system compared to ZF1, I don't think you can make such kind of migration without decent amount of recoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of your code will likely remain the same. It's more like refactoring than rewriting.

For plugins, use the new event system. Register an event listener to fire and do something when the event you are interested in occurs. There is an example of a simple listener to set up the view in the Skeleton Application. There are lots of events you can listen to - lots more flexibility than zf1 - and you can add your own events too.

For action helpers, write your class that does things and inject it into your controller using the DIC. There are lots of injection examples floating around the web. It's much simpler than zf1 really.

For view helpers, it's almost the same as zf1. Subclass from AbstractHelper, and then register that helper in the DI config. You'll find instructions in the zf2 user docs.

I know these comments aren't an exhaustive tutorial, but it should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Events in zf2 make more sense, you have flexibility to hook a process. Is there a library or extensive tutorial that guides through the DIC? It seems as if there are a lot of behaviors in the DIC that I need to learn.

Comment: zf2 has moved somewhat since making this comment. A serviceManager has been introduced, which surplants the DIC in many instances. Now you write a factory class and do most of your injections that way (it's faster). Also, I was mistaken, there are action plugins, much like view helpers (plugins) in zf2, so you don't have to use only the DIC/ServiceManager. Finally, as for tutorials, reading the source is best at present - otherwise it is a moving target. (There were over 400 merged pull requests between beta 3 and 4!) Things should settle down with the first Relese Candidate.